# Getting bookmark count from delicious

Tags: delicious-api

I was previously retreiving this through url:s like:

http://feed.delicious.com/v2/json/url/f17d3aaa8fd2d271877f1ee773b89145

Where f17d3aaa8fd2d271877f1ee773b89145 is a md5 of the url.

This longer seems to be working? Is this temporary or is the API discontinued? Any replacement?

Previous similar question on this topic on SO from a few years ago seems to have been temporary issues.

Answer (score 0):

The new API URL is https://api.del.icio.us/

Therefore, you can find the info you are searching for at https://api.del.icio.us/v2/json/url/f17d3aaa8fd2d271877f1ee773b89145

But I'm not sure how long it will last, I suspect delicious is unfortunately pretty much a dead service today.

Answer (score 0):

The link https://api.del.icio.us/ is not working any more. The API has been shut down. Delicious support is not available any more and not responding to inquiries.